# Des grenouilles plein les poches

Tags: grammaire, accord, syntaxe

There is this phrase in the book *Le Livre de Perle* by Timothée de Fombelle whose grammar I do not understand. I think generally I would say “les poches pleins de grenouilles”. What rules are applied to it? Is it just the literary style?

> Le prince Iån, des grenouilles plein les poches, regardait cette
>   assemblée depuis sa barque.

Comment: Not particularly literary. There are some more examples [here](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2896).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *proposition relative explicative* might be written :

> *..., les poches plein**e**s de grenouilles,...*

where *plein* is an adjective thus need to fully agree with *poches*.

In the book, *[plein](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/plein)* (TLFi: IV) is used as a invariable preposition meaning *largely filling*. This usage was originally colloquial but is now widespread and accepted as correct.